# Multi Authentication problems in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have tried using the multiple authentication laravel tutorials and even have read online everything about this particular error it still isn't working. Help??

> Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::__construct() must
>   implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider, null
>   given, called in

Comment: Please share your `Auth.php`

Comment: Please share your Login controller. Tell us the steps you are taking. What are you doing that produces the problem. We need a bit more info to help you.